# Widget Code / Advanced Custom Fields / Elementor

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I manage a site that needs to display a widget from a ticket provider, code included below. The widget code is the same on every page the only variable is the event ID. With a different widget I was able to simply have the content editor insert the event ID in the corresponding field via ACF and then using elementor I pasted the widget code and used the acf shortcode to replace the event id. This meant that the widget displayed on each page with the correct event id inserted.

However with this new widget every single thing I have tried doesn't work and I can't figure out why so if anyone has any insight that would be amazing. I've tried including the entire code below in a plain text field and then displaying via elementor as html and even that hasn't worked.

```
<style>
    .dice-widget-btn {
      color: inherit;
      border: 1px solid currentColor;
      background: transparent;
      display: inline-block;
      font: inherit;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    <button class="dice-widget-btn" data-dice-id="6242e16cb7275300015bacb3">Book Now</button>
    <div id="dice-overlay-widget"></div>
    <script src="https://widgets.dice.fm/dice-overlay-widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    DiceOverlayWidget.create({});
    </script>
```

Comment: Where does the ID go in that code - is it the data-dice-id on the <button>, or something you need to add to the create() arguments object? Are you still configuring the ID in ACF?

Comment: But if you're just having trouble putting HTML on the page using Elementor then that's probably a question for them directly.